# determine length (or number of digits) of every row in column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with columns that are `floats`. Some rows have `NaN` values.

I want to find rows where the length (or number of digits) of the number is `!=6`.

I tried the following:

```
len(str(df['a'])) != 6
```

But this seems to only return only one Boolean value and not a Boolean for every row in the dataframe.

What is the correct way to do this?

**UPDATE**:

Someone made a post with an answer similar to:

```
df.query('a <= 10**5')
```

That seemed to work nicely. Now, I want to add an additional condition where column b is not null. How do I do that in the query() function.

Comment: if you're trying to find the rows that have `NaN` values, this is the wrong way to do it.

Comment: thats not what I am trying to do. Please re-read.

Comment: what is the length of `1.234` if you would use your algorithm?

Comment: May I ask what the intention behind this is? It feels a little odd to ask for the length of a float's base 10 string representation. Maybe there is a way to capture what you need mathematically?

Comment: I have a column that has numbers. Since pandas treats NaNs as floats this entire column is treated as a float. In reality the numbers when they are not NaN are integers. The numbers are either 6 digits (if I refer to them as integers) or less. I want to find all rows where the number of digits is less than 6. There is no mathematical reason why I want to do this. I need this subset for additional processing which is not relevant to my post.

Comment: Alright, then `df.a < 1e5` is the way to go. RandyC updated their answer already and it looks fine to me, you should go with it ;)

Comment: @codingknob that's what I was trying to get at. I'm pretty sure there are better ways to take your dataset that produces `NaN` and tell pandas to filter out those rows and treat the other values as integers. This is called an XY problem - your problem is actually X but you're trying to solve for Y.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cast it to a string and then use the string ops.

```
df['a'].astype(str).str.len()
```

EDIT: To your more complete version, you might just go with:

```
df[(df['a'].fillna(0) < 100000) & (pd.notnull(df[b]))]
```